# Mocha's beforeEach() and done() function not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mocha.js

I have a very simple test suite written in mocha.
The crazy thing is when I 'make test', I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object],[object Object] has no method 'done'
```

Here is the code:

```
describe('Lists Endpoint (/lists)', function(){

    beforeEach(function(done){
        db.collection('lists').remove(function(err){
            db.collection('lists').insert([{name: 'LPS list', desc: 'Nice list!'}, {name: 'TLB list', desc: 'Cool listo!'}], function(err, records){
                done(); //Throws TypeError
            });            
        });        
    });


    describe('GET /lists', function(){
        it('should return an array of lists', function(done){
            request(app).get('/lists').end(function(err, res){
                res.should.have.status(200);
                res.should.be.json;
                res.body.should.be.an.Array;
                res.body.length.should.eql(2);
                res.body.
                done();
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll extract this line:

```
res.body.
    done();
```

Which is read as `res.body.done();`. There's no `done` method on `res.body` object.

Comment: Wow, I totally didn't see this damn '.'. Thanks a lot!